# Forms Authentication Post From Remote URL

Tags: asp.net, post, authentication, forms-authentication, query-string

Instead of going directly to my forms authentication login page: https://sub.domain.org/forms/Login/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=xyz
and manually entering the username/password:

I am wondering if it is possible to post to an asp.net forms authentication url from a separate page

Example File:
https://sub.domain.org/forms/tests/login.html

```
<html><head><title>Test Page...</title></head> 
   <body>Connecting... 
   <form name="login" method="post" action="https://sub.domain.org/forms/Login/default.aspx"> 
   <input type="hidden" name= "username" value="someusername"> 
   <input type="hidden " name="password" value="somepassword"> 
   </form><script language="JavaScript"> 
   document.login.submit(); 
   </script></body></html>
```

However, all this does is redirect to the login page.
https://sub.domain.org/forms/Login/default.aspx
It doesn't seem to create the session cookie.

I am trying to implement something like this between a portal authentication and my webforms authentication.  The portal has support for running some code like above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Here is the web.config section for the forms authentication based login application: https://sub.domain.org/forms/Login/default.aspx

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

  <machineKey
    validationKey="3404677AC408C9E2EED87F8418FE2DD0D2AB8D0E824F5B53AC9133F7CC7152F4388E614C267D6DB04638CF6D1C19E55EB052FFD4273DEA04863829E1BFE9CDE4"
    decryptionKey="C9668F6C98502220633033B21818EE57D6F903FC48C2A94B5EC99B8BC1F3F411"
    validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />

</system.web>
```

There is no web.config for the page that is posting to the login url.  It is a simple html page: https://sub.domain.org/forms/tests/login.html  as shown above.

Comment: So, this is not from a "Remote Url", it is from another page which has the login form and that this page is a different page from what is configured in the web.config for forms authentication?

Comment: It will ultimately be from a "Remote URL", I just kept it the same for simplicity of the question.  The user will authenticate through a portal using their ldap credentials.  The portal allows for running some code for SSO to external applications through "connectors". If they already authenticated through the portal I want to POST to the "forms authentication" page (all my apps outside the portal use) to create the session cookie without having them have to manually log in.

Answer (score 0):

I dig this up for you.
http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com.au/2006/10/cross-application-forms-authentication.html

It seems you need to add to for forms authent web.config

```
enableCrossAppRedirects="true"
```

You also need to put some authentication keys that must match between the applications.

Hopefully that will prevent your problem with redirection.

Comment: It does not create the session cookie even if the two pages are on the same server/domain.

Comment: update your question by posting your forms authentication web.config part for both applications.

Comment: I have updated the question with the information you requested.